# Problemas no select utilizando Having MAX expressão não booleana

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Preciso fazer um select pra pegar todos os pacientes que consultaram em um periodo de tempo em um setor especifico, e ver quando foi o ultimo retorno deles, e se eles tiverem mais de um ano que não vem nesse mesmo setor , e depois um outro select bem parecido mas que ai eles até voltaram para outras consultas, mas não nessse setor X

A parte incial do select é

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT osm_pac, osm_dthr 
FROM osm 
WHERE osm_serie BETWEEN 115 AND 119  
AND osm_str = 'GLA' 
GROUP BY osm_pac 
HAVING MAX (osm_dthr)
```

que quando eu to dando esse having max o compilador me volta

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.
```

Isso em teoria traria os pacientes que consultaram no setor GLA com a ultima data de atendimento deles.

Claro que por enquanto esses valores são só numericos, depois que vou fazer o join com a tabela onde fica os nomes dos pacientes

Answer (score 1):

Cara acredito que faltou comparar o codigo dos pacientes na clausula having:

```
SELECT DISTINCT osm_pac, osm_dthr 
FROM osm 
WHERE osm_serie BETWEEN 115 AND 119  
AND osm_str = 'GLA' 
GROUP BY osm_pac 
HAVING MAX (osm_dthr) = osm_dthr
```

Comment: Olá Germano!

Sua ajuda foi essencial! 

Consegui adequar o select só precisei tambem usar o group by com o osm_dthr

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT osm_pac, osm_dthr 
FROM osm 
WHERE osm_serie BETWEEN 115 AND 119  
AND osm_str = 'GLA' 
GROUP BY osm_pac, osm_dthr
HAVING MAX (osm_dthr) = osm_dthr
```